# How to define which language code I want to see in Sandcastle's HFB documentation?

Tags: c#, documentation-generation

that's a rather difficult one :
I use Sandcastle Help File Builder to produce documentation for my C# project from Visual Studio 2010. I want to make code only visible for C# but in default there are also visible pieces of code for C++ and Visual Basic as shown on the screenshot : 
[image]

How can I change this ? I mean here how can I change it in project creation options to produce only an .html for C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can limit the syntax examples to specific coding languages by setting the Project Properties->Help File->SyntaxFilters property.

[edit] Screenshot is below - Certain firewall filters will block the hosted image.

[image: SandCastle Help File Builder Project Properties window]